# EventHubTrigger what is happening with the checkpoints?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

We are upgrading our eventhub package to latest webjobs.eventhub which now uses `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs`.

We use EventHubTrigger.

Checkpoint seems to have changed, and I am trying to understand what this change will do.

where it used to be

```
azure-webjobs-eventhub/{namespace}/{eventhub}/{consumergroup}/{partitionfile}
```

it is now -

```
azure-webjobs-eventhub/{namespace}/{eventhub}/{consumergroup}/checkpoint/{partitionfile}

azure-webjobs-eventhub/{namespace}/{eventhub}/{consumergroup}/ownership/{partitionfile}
```

I understand the change and fine, we can still upgrade we can start the eventhub from a time so that it doesn't start consuming everything.

However, what I am concerned about is:

all the partition files are "blank" they are "0 bytes" in both checkpoint folder and ownership folder.

I am not seeing any other place where this checkpoint is maintained.

I assume it is doing this in memory while the app is running, but what about if I stopped my app and rerun will it start again, because I cannot see how it could continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upgrade the bindings, the v5.x line will read the legacy checkpoint and preserve your previous location in the stream.  When a new checkpoint is written, it will be in the current format and will take precedence over the legacy instance going forward.

Checkpoint and ownership information for the `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` family of packages are stored in the metadata for the blob.  This allows it to be queried and modified without the need to download the blob content and perform serialization.